# Embed secure layer into .EXE using C++

Tags: c++, security, embed, exe, file-sharing

I started a project with a friend of me and we wanted to create an security application for windows using c++.
We decided to create a program that could "lock" an executable.

We found this useful if we where to send the program to someone else, store it safely on an USB/Disk and to learn more about executables.
The program will imbed itself into the 'host' executable and encrypt the programs binary. Then, when the program is launched, our imbedded program asks for the password and unlocks/decrypts itself without need of the original program, so you could unlock it on any computer without needing the original program.

Here is my question:
"How to I embed the extra security layer into the already existing program?" and "Is this possible?".

Also, if such program already exists, where can i possibly find it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use winrar for it. SFX-archive and also you can add command (for run program, in your example) that will execute after archive will unpacket.

Comment: @KonstantinT. but then the user should have winrar installed. I know alot of people have this installed anyway, but not everyone.

Comment: No, they shouldn't.  SFX is self extracting archive. It not require winrar for extracting.